# Python implementation of redis zset?

Tags: python, data-structures

Does exist redis zset implemented in python? If not, how would you design it in python?

Redis [zset](http://www.redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#sorted-sets) is a set ordered by score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis sorted set is implemented with [Skiplist](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c).